# Android Notifications Locale specific message with Unicode

Tags: android, unicode, locale

Hi I want to use local regional language text in notification , i could send the unicode of text and it works properly where device supports the language. but to support on all the devices  i want to set the type face (custom fonts) to notification text..I tried with RemoteView but no luck. Here the notification code sample which i used..

```
public void handleNotification(BitMap notificationIcon,String title,String message,){
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification);
   remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.push_subject, title);



    message = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(message);
remoteViews.
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message);
//the message is somethisng like unicode "\u092d\u093e\u0930\u0924 \u0915\u0940 \u0930\u093e\u091c\u0928\u0940\u0924\u093f\u0915"


remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, notificationIcon);
final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context).setTicker(message)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setContent(remoteViews);
Notification n;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        n = builder.getNotification();
    } else {
        builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
        if (largeBitmap != null) {
            builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(largeBitmap).setBigContentTitle(title)
                    .setSummaryText(message));
        }
        n = builder.build();
        n.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
    }

    n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(0, n);
}
```

I think there may be another way to do this or just a simple way to present a notification message text in locale specific language.Any help appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: is Unicode coming in text of that particular language?

Comment: No @Anjali Tripathi It's only encoded Unicode

Comment: what text are you sending on server is encoded unicode or text ?

Comment: Yes It is encoded hindi Unicode

Comment: try my answer. I also had same issue

Comment: thank you @Anjali Tripathi, your answer is working .But I need some more implementation for checking that the current device is supports the specific Locale's that it supports and if the locale one which we are setting is not supported by device I'm not going to display the Local. Simply i can show the message language not supported by the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending encoded Unicode of that particular language then try commons-lang-2.6 jar by this link

http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonslang26jar.htm

Use: add this line to your notification class

```
  StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text)
//here text(Notification text)must be Unicode of that language
```

Comment: Do you write the code by device keyboard or bring from somewhere ?

Comment: Its not by keyboard written code.It is taken from outside language to unicode

Comment: sry I can't this is my first quest'n after i get the 16 reputations i'll definately vote it up :)